# Overridden mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) does not change JFrame’s component JLable?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouseevent

I implemented a `JFrame` that contains some `JLable`'s. I would like to change their appearance once they are clicked. The appended code should do so. In fact: It does *not*. Taking the same code and putting it into the run of an inner Thread-class does the job. The inner Thread-instance inverts the clicked `JLable` twice.

Can anybody give me a hint why the `mouseClicked`-method seems not to be able to affect the clicked `JLable`'s appearance?

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (clickable) {
        for (Position p : positions.keySet()) {
            JLabel lable = positions.get(p);
            if (lable == e.getComponent()) {

                pickedPosition = p;
                LOGGER.info(pickedPosition + " pressed");

                synchronized (lable) {
                    // store old colors
                    Color obg = lable.getBackground();
                    Color ofg = lable.getForeground();
                    // invert them
                    Color nbg = new Color(255 - obg.getRed(), 255 - obg.getGreen(), 255 - obg.getBlue());
                    Color nfg = new Color(255 - ofg.getRed(), 255 - ofg.getGreen(), 255 - ofg.getBlue());
                    // set them
                    lable.setOpaque(true);
                    lable.setForeground(nfg);
                    lable.setBackground(nbg);
                    // wait a while
                    try {
                        lable.wait(WAIT_WHILE_INVERTING_MS);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException i) {
                        LOGGER.warn(i.getMessage());
                    }
                    // switch back to initial
                    lable.setBackground(obg);
                    lable.setForeground(ofg);
                }

                e.consume();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `lable.wait(WAIT_WHILE_INVERTING_MS);` may suspend the ui thread, therefore it can't render your change. Try to do this change in it's own thread or try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for the `synchronized` block of code. All code executed from the event code will execute on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Since you should always update the properties of components on the EDT you don't need to worry about other threads updating the component.

It looks like you want to temporarily change the Color of the label. The problem is the wait() method will block the EDT and prevent the GUI from repainting itself.

You can either:

1. Use a SwingWorker to start a Thread and then sleep for a period of time. Then when the worker is finished you can restore the color of the label. See [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples.
2. Use a Swing Timer to schedule the changes. See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information.